# Dynamic replacement of radio buttons in a controlgroup

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I need to be able to dynamically replace the radio buttons in a controlgroup. I've come up with a solution, but I'm wanting to make sure I'm going about it the right way. [Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/floyd_may/7Qnyz/).

Should I be manually modifying the classes after calling `.checkboxradio()` on each of the newly-created radio buttons, or is there a method in jQuery Mobile somewhere that will help me accomplish this?

**Please note that the jsFiddle here works as I need it to.** I'm asking if there's an easier (or more idiomatic) way to update the dynamically-created radio buttons' visual styles to conform to the controlgroup style.

Answer (score -1):

Content should be added to the DOM before jquery mobile enhancement, for instance by binding to the `page beforecreate` event instead of the page `pagebeforeshow`. This way your content will be properly enhanced.

As for dynamic content, you can enhance it as soon as it has been inserted in the DOM. See [this modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8cWF/).

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't notice that in your modified jsFiddle, the controlgroup's display is all wrong, with every radio button having corners. This is the whole point of this question.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
    $('#creneauListPage #fieldcontain input').checkboxradio();
    $('#creneauListPage #fieldcontain .ui-btn').removeClass('ui-btn-corner-all');
    $('#creneauListPage #fieldcontain .ui-btn:first').addClass('ui-corner-top');
    $('#creneauListPage #fieldcontain .ui-btn:last').addClass('ui-corner-bottom ui-controlgroup-last');
```